Why do many night shots use streets that are wet?
In many movies and TV shows that I have seen, when there is an exterior night shot that includes some streets, those streets often times seem wet.  This seems to happen regardless of the "weather" occurring during that scene  EG the streets will be wet even if there is no or has been no rain.
Is there a reason for doing this?
Lighting during a night scene is related, but doesn't touch on any wet aspect
As a classic example (and by no means the only one) from BttF

Image from https://backtothefuture.fandom.com/wiki/Twin_Pines_Mall

Can you name or, preferably, show examples? My guess to an answer would be that more reflection means more light entering the camera, making it easier to get a clearer image. It's also much easier to get a sense of space when there are more reflective surfaces.

Doing a quick Google search of "movie production night shots wet streets" gave a lot of hits all saying the same thing

@CGCampbell which sounds like an answer

I'm at work and cannot actually read/see most of the sites, I added that one because it was from a filmakingish site. So, no answer from me. All I can see of most of the hits is Google's little two line information. When I actually try to hit the sites themselves, just about all of them are blocked to me.

More reflective surfaces give a clearer image. Not only does more reflected light mean a clearer camera image, it also gives a greater sense of the environment, of the space, and of the surfaces that constitute it.
Additionally, a "wet down" also helps diffusing the reflections of lights used to film the scene and the shadows of other equipment. As someone on cinematography.com puts it:

It creates some texture and life to what would be an otherwise black void (in the case of asphalt). It reflects your light sources, and because most of the light hits the water in an "edge" position, they tend to go hot so one needs to stay on top of that.


So basically it makes the scene brighter and more visually interesting?

@bob Exactly. What I gleaned from the online threads that discuss this is that apart from giving more visual information, it is generally found to be more beautiful by cinematographers (and photographers). And that at this point it's almost so common that it's a standard procedure.

I always thought it was a good way of showing us vertical space while having the camera low or aimed towards the ground (where the action might be).

It may change how the scene is viewed, but every time I see this effect I have to wonder "When did it rain?"

Is it also a factor that rain happens quite often in real life too — and that it's straightforward to turn a dry surface wet, but much harder to turn a wet one convincingly dry, and so if there's any possibility of rain during any of the shoot, choosing a wet look could avoid delays?

To add to the good answer and comments here, know that "wet streets at night" was already a well-worn cinematic meme in September 1964.
Artist Mort Drucker, writing for that month's issue of Mad Magazine, created a parody of The Fugitive TV show, which he called The Phewgitive, a tongue-in-cheek reference to "Phew, I almost got caught!"
The last panel of his layout shows a worker for the Making Streets Look Like it Just Rained Company holding a thick hose as the episode concludes. Sixty years later, I still remember the laugh that this genius observation of Mort Drucker gave me, and the countless times I've thought of this panel for all the "wet street at night" movie scenes that I've seen since then.


After finding out that this is a thing, I'm now wondering at the requirements for "making it look like it just rained".  You need to cover a wide area with a sheen of water, but you can't leave a torrent flowing.  And you probably need to keep touching it up during production.

@PeterM So, in Mort Drucker's mind, there must be a company for that!

@PeterM - they do a top up between every take (if required), and it isn't a torrential downpour, its more like a wide spray from multiple hoses by a couple of the crew.

companies like this - https://1stdefensefire.co.uk/film-tv/ offer set wet-down services, and this is what it looks like on set: https://imgur.com/k9fEZa0 (probably a marvel movie)

Areas of the screen which are saturated white or black, or are filled with a uniform shade, will tend to appear as flat objects.  In the absence of other depth cues, they will typically appear in a plane is parallel to the screen, especially if they have sharp edges.  This is fine for things like superimposed titles, but could be very distracting for things like road surfaces which are typically not quite flat.
If a road is part of a purpose-built set, a set designer can ensure that no parts of the road will appear as solid black.  Actual road surfaces, however, may have regions that would be indistinguishable from black.  When using digital cameras that allow a live preview, areas that would be too dark may be identified before shooting, but film doesn't offer such luxury.
Moistening pavement prior to filming is a way of ensuring that none of it will be too dark, and moistening all pavement will be less distracting than having a few areas which were moistened for fear they might otherwise be too dark.  Further, since it's not terribly uncommon for some regions of asphalt to appear shiny when try, pavement that is uniformly slightly moist will usually not call excessive attention to itself.

In addition to simply looking prettier with night-time lighting, a rainy environment is naturally associated with the night. This perception works even if you have to light up the scene to almost the same APL as daytime, which has been done to make the action visible in cinema's early days.
This perception is founded in reality: it does rain more during the nighttime than during the daytime.

source
Air is colder during the night, and cold air can hold less water than warm air, by a large enough margin for day vs night to make a difference. All that extra water that formed clouds during the day needs to go somewhere when it gets colder.

source
So the trope that it (usually/always) rains at night is both cinematic and reasonably realistic.

I live in a desert and most of my rain (when we get it) is monsoonal during the day time. /s

@PeterM I didn't know there was a desert in Hollywood, or have people learned to live elsewhere?

Not in Hollywood but I can see genuine local film studios from my house.
